# CGContextStrokePath(context) crashes. Why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, quartz-2d, cgcontext

I'm new to Quartz 2D and the world of contexts. why is this code crashing ?

```
NSMutableData* pdfData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:1000];

CGRect bounds = (CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100));
NSDictionary* documentInfo = nil;

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData (pdfData,
                                 bounds,
                                 documentInfo);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
NSLog (@"context: %@", context);

// Drawing lines with a white stroke color
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
// Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

// Draw a single line from left to right
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10.0, 30.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, 30.0);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

[pdfData release];
```

The code crashes at CGContextStrokePath(context) with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question to paste in the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you draw to a PDF graphics context, you need to create a page with  `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage` or  `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo`.

```
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage(bounds, nil);
```

Comment: yes indeed. thank you.  do you know if the nsmutabledata* PdfData gets retained within the context ? or is this something that I need to retain separately. (I need to have one context that gets written to by different classes one by one and then close it off with the resulting pdf data)

Comment: If Apple sticks to the rules, it is retained until you called `UIGraphicsEndPDFContext`, which is required and currently missing in your code. I'm pretty sure they stick to the rules.

Comment: thank you! do you know how to access the pdfData after (or just before ?) UIGraphicsEndPDFContext. I need to send it back to the caller when I'm done drawing to the context (so either a pdf file can be created from it ... or just re-used as raw pdf data)